# SharePoint Online Auth Cookie TTL

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication

I am using SharePoint REST web services from a third paty application.

In doing so I need to obtain a SPOIDCRL cookie as described here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/223602/60157

Once I have a SPOIDCRL cookie I make my REST api requests with this cookie attached to each one. It works fine. But I'm worried about session expiration when this cookie will become expired.

How long, by default, do SharePoint online `SPOIDCRL` cookies last before expiring?

Is this something that can be changed in the https://(tenant)-admin.sharepoint.com web UI? If so where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/15e5ffd2-a6d7-45ae-bd1d-9780f62e17c3/sp-online-active-authentication-cookiespoidcrl-lifespan?forum=onlineservicessharepoint).  I assume this is what your are trying to do... maybe not.
But, i think these two links are closer to what you may be looking for:

- [Configurable token lifetimes in Azure Active Directory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes)
- [Changes to the Token Lifetime Defaults in Azure AD](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2017/08/31/changes-to-the-token-lifetime-defaults-in-azure-ad/)

if none of these suit you, then you may be wading into the undocumented backwaters of O365 as seen [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-Active-Directory/Office-365-Access-and-Refresh-Tokens/td-p/166760).

As per this [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/15e5ffd2-a6d7-45ae-bd1d-9780f62e17c3/sp-online-active-authentication-cookiespoidcrl-lifespan?forum=onlineservicessharepoint) The `SPOIDCRL` cookie is refreshed on each page load.
You cannot alter the duration of the cookie's existence in the Admin Console in SPO.  Without knowing more about what you are trying to do, i cannot be more specific

[Here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/session-timeouts-for-office-365-37a5c116-5b07-4f70-8333-5b86fd2c3c40) is a general guide to security token expiration in O365, but the `SPOIDCRL` cookie is not enumerated in this link (nor are any other O365 cookies).

---

Please remember to Up Vote and Mark as an Answer if this helped you.

Comment: None of those things helped me, but that is my fault. my question was vague. i updated my question. I can make hundreds of calls with the same SPOIDCRL cookie.